# Is there any way to detect a drop-in braintree.js form's submit click?

Tags: javascript, braintree

I'm using a braintree.js drop in form. I'm submitting it with ajax, by registering for the `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback. So far so good, it works fine.

However, after submitting the form, there's a two step process: first the payment details are submitted to braintree and verified (while a spinner shows over the form), then the details on the page are anonymised, and the `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback fires with a nonce I can use to send to my server.

The problem is I'd like to disable the form submission button when it's clicked, but registering an `onClick` handler on it causes braintree to ignore the click.

I understand that the customer's card details are visible on the page at this point, but I can't grab them anyway due to the iframe being from a different domain, and any potential method I could use at this point to grab the details I could do with `setInterval()` anyway, so I don't really see a security case for this.

Is there any way to detect the click here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

To my knowledge you can't jump in the middle of the tokenization process with the Drop-In. It sounds like you are looking to create a custom experience for your users that steps [beyond the Drop-In use case](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/drop-in).

Enabling a form submit button after the `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback is the common Drop-In use flow, but by creating a custom integration you can directly [handle the client-side tokenization process](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+dotnet/guides/credit-cards/client-side#tokenize-card) and wrap it with whatever functionality you need:

```
var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: "CLIENT-TOKEN-FROM-SERVER"});

client.tokenizeCard({
  number: "4111111111111111",
  expirationDate: "10/20"
}, function (err, nonce) {
  // Send nonce to your server
});
```